# When initialising jquery Cycle2 slideshow, can the .cycle() method be called on a variable container name?

Tags: php, jquery, cycle2

I have a php object that creates inline JavaScript from templates and injects it into pages where requested. like so:

```
echo ScriptEngine::inject('CycleSlideshow', $args);
```

where `CycleSlideshow` is the name of the script template and `$args` is an array of options.

I am trying to create a template for malsups jquery [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin but am having trouble getting the `.cycle()` method to run when called on a variable container name like so:

```
<script>
  var container = '<?php echo $args['container']; ?>';
  function initCycle() {
    $(container).cycle({
      /** ... options here .... **/
    });
  }
</script>
```

However, if I echo the container name directly into the initialisation call instead of storing it in a variable the slide show initialises just fine. eg:

```
<script>
  function initCycle() {
    $('<?php echo $args['container']; ?>').cycle({
      /** ... options here .... **/
    });
  }
</script>
```

I want to store the container name in a variable because I have other functions (pause, resume, reinit, etc) I want to be able to call on the container and it looks better to use a JS variable than it does to keep echoing in from php. But it doesn't seem to work.

Is this not supported? I can't find anything saying it isn't on the Cycle2 website.